# Looking to highlight values in Bold but the function is not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to highlight some values in bold but it is not working on my jupyter notebook. Can someone comment on this please.

```
def highlight(x):
    return ['font-weight: bold' if v < 0 else ''
                for v in x]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2))
print(df)
df.style.apply(highlight)

display(df)
```

My output is as below

```
        0         1
0   0.310631    0.755780
1   -1.877079   0.136980
2   -0.064271   0.653984
3   -0.395941   0.030710
4   0.350555    0.095487
```

Negative values are not highlighted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following to display style using the `display()` function:

```
display(df.style.apply(highlight))
```

or in Jupyter Notebook you can simply write in a cell the `df.style.apply()` function to visualize it.

```
df.style.apply(highlight)
```